# Display all the items into the div display box

Tags: php, function, variables, mysqli, scope

Here i am trying to display all the items in the div display area. However i keep getting these errors;

> Notice: Undefined variable: connect in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\landlord_profile.php on line 76
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\landlord_profile.php on line 76
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\landlord_profile.php on line 78

```
<?php
session_start(); 

include ("includes/connect.php");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Landlord Profile</title>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="whole_page_div" style="width:100%; height:935px;;">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 15px;>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="logo" style="margin-left: 750px;"><a href="Index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"/></a></div>
                 <a href="logout.php"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="logout" value="Log out" style="background-color:#337AB7; margin-top: -130px; margin-left: 1600px; ">Log Out</button></a>

                </div>


<hr>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top topnav" role="navigation">
    <div class="container topnav">


            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand topnav" href="#">MyAstonSpace</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Undergraduate Information">Undergraduate Information</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Post-Grad Information">Post-Grad Information</a>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#International Students">International Students</a>
                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#Contact Us ">Contact Us </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>


    <?php
    function getprop (){

        $getprop = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM properties");

        while ($rowprop = mysqli_fetch_array($getprop)){

            $prop_id = $rowprop['prop_id'];
            $prop_name = $rowprop['prop_name'];
            $prop_address = $rowprop['prop_address'];
            $prop_img = $rowprop['prop_img'];
            $prop_radius = $rowprop['prop_radius'];
            $prop_bedrooms = $rowprop['prop_bedrooms'];
            $prop_type = $rowprop['prop_type'];
            $prop_price = $rowprop['prop_price'];

            echo "
                <div class='singleproperty'>

                <h3>$prop_name</h3>
            "   ;       

            }


        }


    ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>Your Profile <h5> Landlord </5></h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="width:300px;">
     <li><a href="#">Personal Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="includes/landlord_profile.php">My Proporties</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Upload Profile Image</a></li>
    <li><a href="incldues/deactivate_myaccount.php">Deactivate My Account</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>


<center>
<div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 1200px; height: 400px; margin-top: -200px; margin-left: 100px; border: 2px solid blue;  " >
    <div class="panel-body" style="text-align:center; margin-left:30px; margin-bottom:10px;"> 
        <div class="listproperties">
        <?php
        getprop();
        ?>
        </div>

     </div>
</div>
</center>


<?php
include ("includes/footer-inc.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose `$connect` is defined in your `includes/connect.php`. You try to access that variable in a function which simply has no access to this variable (aka is in another scope).

You should add `$connect` as a parameter to your function `getprop()` to make it accessible:

```
function getprop ($connect) {
  ...
}
```

Each time you use that function add the param by using

```
getprop($connect);
```

instead of

```
getprop();
```

Another possibility would be the use of a global variable but this is really bad coding style so don't do that.

You should read the manual page aboout variable scopes which explains who can access which variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Its because your variable `$connect` is used inside function.

But, its not accessible there.

Use [global](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) like:

```
function getprop (){
  global $connect;
// Your code ...
```